# Select within a select slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently use a select within a select to check if data exists in a table:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.desc,
    a.serial,
    a.partno,
    a.maintact,
    a.lcnalc,
    a.datedue,
    a.intrem,
    a.lifetype,
    (select b.id from assets b where
        (b.maintact = a.maintact) and
        (b.aircraft_id = a.aircraft_id) and
        (b.inittype = "STRT") and
        (b.initlcnalc = a.lcnalc OR b.initlcnalc = "")) as parent
    from assets a where aircraft_id = 6;
```

What I would like to know is a more efficient way to do the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` it will be faster:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.desc,
    a.serial,
    a.partno,
    a.maintact,
    a.lcnalc,
    a.datedue,
    a.intrem,
    a.lifetype,
    b.id
from assets a 
join assets b
    ON (b.maintact = a.maintact) and
    (b.aircraft_id = a.aircraft_id) and
    (b.inittype = "STRT") and
    (b.initlcnalc = a.lcnalc OR b.initlcnalc = "")
where a.aircraft_id = 6;
```

Comment: BTW the `LEFT JOIN` will decay into a plain `JOIN` , once you add the `(b.inittype = "STRT")` constant condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with a `left join` to be sure that you get all the rows from `assets`.  The following is close to what you want:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.desc,
    a.serial,
    a.partno,
    a.maintact,
    a.lcnalc,
    a.datedue,
    a.intrem,
    a.lifetype,
    b.parent
from assets a left outer join
     (select maintact, aircraft_id, lcnalc, id
      from assets a
      group by maintact, aircraft_id, lcnal
     ) b
     on b.maintact = a.maintact) and
        (b.aircraft_id = a.aircraft_id) and
        (b.inittype = 'STRT') and
        (b.initlcnalc = a.lcnalc)
where a.aircraft_id = 6;
```

The caveat is the expression `b.initlcnalc = a.lcnalc OR b.initlcnalc = ""`.  I'm not sure exactly what this is supposed to do.  It is likely to introduce duplicate rows in your output.  You might need a second join to handle this case.